# Passing jQuery variable to PHP for error-handling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, error-handling

So I have taken a look around and I cannot seem to find the answer!

I'm trying to send a jQuery variable to PHP.

Code will explain it easier:

jQuery:

```
$error = 0;
$pageName = $(document).find("title").text();
$referrer = document.referrer;

if ($pageName == "Index") {
    $('#index').hide();
    console.log($pageName);

} else if ($pageName == "Testing") {
    $('#testing').hide();
    console.log($pageName);

} else if ($pageName == 'Test') {
    $('#test').hide();
    console.log($pageName);

} else {
    $error = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Ajax/post.php",
        data: { param: $error, ref: $referrer }
    }).done(function (msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + $pageName + " " + $referrer ); 
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$error = $_POST['param']; //I have also tried putting '$error' here.
$referrer = $_POST['ref'];

if ($error == 1)
{
    error_log("There has been an error with the pageName = " . $error . $referrer,
    1,"Email@host.com","From: Email@host.com");
}
?>
```

TL;DR:
I am checking for the  in my pages and then doing some jQuery functions, if the  is unknown then email an error.

So the result I am getting in my email is "1" and that is it. Just the number 1 (which I presume is the $error value?

I'm just playing around with some error handling.

Comment: in PHP, concatenate by "." (dot), not "+"

Comment: That's great! I just started learning PHP. Now the email is "There has been an error with the pageName = 1"

Comment: OK found it, so the "$referrer = document.referrer;" == ""

It wasn't appearing. Anyone got a better idea to find out what page they came from?

Answer (score 0):

Check the if in PHP... the equals operator is ==, not =

```
 if ($error==1)
```

Comment: Sorry yeah I was editing it to remove some stuff and accidentally change it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do an `alert($pageName)` before the first if. Is it the expected value? Also, note that you are sending the ajax request only when the $pageName is _unknown_.

Comment: So the $pageName = <title> which on the error page ="Error" so i would expect the $pageName to always have a <title>. So yes it is the expected value.

Comment: So then is logical: `$error` is 1 in PHP because you are sending it from JS (`$error = 1`) through `$_POST['param']`. I really don't know what is the problem...